# Creating Azure Traffic Manager through REST API - unexpected behaviour

Tags: azure

I created Traffic Manager throught its REST API using 2011-10-01 MS verion.

Resources I followed -

- Create Profile -
  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh758254.aspx
- Create Definition -
  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh758257.aspx

Traffic Manager got created successfully. All happies.

**But after 30mins of time, traffic manager is going to INACTIVE status and all its endpoints are GONE. It shows there are no endpoints associated with it.**

I am not sure what is happening around. Is it Azure problem? or is it REST API problem? or is it my way of creating Traffic manager problem.

PS - I followed this sample for making REST API calls - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/gg651127.aspx

Any help would be highly appreciated.

**UPDATE1**

**Parameters**

- SubscriptionID - a Valid GUID from publishsettings
- Certificate - I cross checked a valid certificate present in the local cert store
- endpoint1 domain name - JASH13.CLOUDAPP.NET
- endpoint2 domain name - JASH23.CLOUDAPP.NET

**There is no error at REST API calls level. Everything worked seamlessly.**

Profile Creation -

```
 // X.509 certificate variables.
            X509Store certStore = null;
            X509Certificate2Collection certCollection = null;
            X509Certificate2 certificate = null;

            // Request and response variables.
            HttpWebRequest httpWebRequest = null;
            HttpWebResponse httpWebResponse = null;

            // Stream variables.
            Stream responseStream = null;
            StreamReader reader = null;

            // URI variable.
            Uri requestUri = null;

            // The thumbprint for the certificate. This certificate would have been
            // previously added as a management certificate within the Windows Azure management portal.
            string thumbPrint = CertificateThumbprint;

            // Open the certificate store for the current user.
            certStore = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
            certStore.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);

            // Find the certificate with the specified thumbprint.
            certCollection = certStore.Certificates.Find(
                                 X509FindType.FindByThumbprint,
                                 thumbPrint,
                                 false);

            // Close the certificate store.
            certStore.Close();

            // Check to see if a matching certificate was found.
            if (0 == certCollection.Count)
            {
                throw new Exception("No certificate found containing thumbprint " + thumbPrint);
            }

            // A matching certificate was found.
            certificate = certCollection[0];


            // Create the request.
            requestUri = new Uri("https://management.core.windows.net/"
                                 + SubscriptionId
                                 + "/services/WATM/profiles");

            httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(requestUri);

            // Add the certificate to the request.
            httpWebRequest.ClientCertificates.Add(certificate);
            httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";
            httpWebRequest.Headers.Add("x-ms-version", "2011-10-01");


            string str = @"<Profile xmlns=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/windowsazure""><DomainName>" + ProfileDomain + "</DomainName><Name>" + ProfileName + "</Name></Profile>";
            byte[] bodyStart = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(str.ToString());
            Stream dataStream = httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream();
            dataStream.Write(bodyStart, 0, str.ToString().Length);

            // Make the call using the web request.
            httpWebResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();

            // Parse the web response.
            responseStream = httpWebResponse.GetResponseStream();
            reader = new StreamReader(responseStream);

            // Close the resources no longer needed.
            httpWebResponse.Close();
            responseStream.Close();
            reader.Close();
```

Definition Creation-

```
 // X.509 certificate variables.
            X509Store certStore = null;
            X509Certificate2Collection certCollection = null;
            X509Certificate2 certificate = null;

            // Request and response variables.
            HttpWebRequest httpWebRequest = null;
            HttpWebResponse httpWebResponse = null;

            // Stream variables.
            Stream responseStream = null;
            StreamReader reader = null;

            // URI variable.
            Uri requestUri = null;

            // The thumbprint for the certificate. This certificate would have been
            // previously added as a management certificate within the Windows Azure management portal.
            string thumbPrint = CertificateThumbprint;

            // Open the certificate store for the current user.
            certStore = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
            certStore.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);

            // Find the certificate with the specified thumbprint.
            certCollection = certStore.Certificates.Find(
                                 X509FindType.FindByThumbprint,
                                 thumbPrint,
                                 false);

            // Close the certificate store.
            certStore.Close();

            // Check to see if a matching certificate was found.
            if (0 == certCollection.Count)
            {
                throw new Exception("No certificate found containing thumbprint " + thumbPrint);
            }

            // A matching certificate was found.
            certificate = certCollection[0];


            // Create the request.
            requestUri = new Uri("https://management.core.windows.net/"
                                 + SubscriptionId
                                 + "/services/WATM/profiles/" + ProfileName + "/definitions");

            httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(requestUri);

            // Add the certificate to the request.
            httpWebRequest.ClientCertificates.Add(certificate);
            httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";
            httpWebRequest.Headers.Add("x-ms-version", "2011-10-01");


            string str = @"<Definition xmlns=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/windowsazure""><DnsOptions><TimeToLiveInSeconds>300</TimeToLiveInSeconds></DnsOptions><Monitors><Monitor><IntervalInSeconds>30</IntervalInSeconds><TimeoutInSeconds>10</TimeoutInSeconds><ToleratedNumberOfFailures>3</ToleratedNumberOfFailures><Protocol>HTTP</Protocol><Port>80</Port><HttpOptions><Verb>GET</Verb><RelativePath>/</RelativePath><ExpectedStatusCode>200</ExpectedStatusCode></HttpOptions></Monitor></Monitors><Policy><LoadBalancingMethod>RoundRobin</LoadBalancingMethod><Endpoints><Endpoint><DomainName>" + PrimaryService + "</DomainName><Status>Enabled</Status></Endpoint><Endpoint><DomainName>" + SecondaryService + "</DomainName><Status>Enabled</Status></Endpoint></Endpoints></Policy></Definition>";
            byte[] bodyStart = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(str.ToString());
            Stream dataStream = httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream();
            dataStream.Write(bodyStart, 0, str.ToString().Length);

            // Make the call using the web request.
            httpWebResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();

            // Parse the web response.
            responseStream = httpWebResponse.GetResponseStream();
            reader = new StreamReader(responseStream);

            // Close the resources no longer needed.
            httpWebResponse.Close();
            responseStream.Close();
            reader.Close();
```

**UPDATE2**
Once the TM went into Inactive State, I checked the profile definition using REST API. In there I was not able to find any endpoints. They are missing.

```
        <Definitions xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/windowsazure" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <Definition>
    <DnsOptions>
    <TimeToLiveInSeconds>300</TimeToLiveInSeconds>
    </DnsOptions>
    <Status>Enabled</Status>
    <Version>1</Version>
    <Monitors>
    <Monitor>
<IntervalInSeconds>30</IntervalInSeconds>
<TimeoutInSeconds>10</TimeoutInSeconds>
<ToleratedNumberOfFailures>3</ToleratedNumberOfFailures>
<Protocol>HTTP</Protocol>
<Port>80</Port>
<HttpOptions>
<Verb>GET</Verb>
<RelativePath>/</RelativePath>
<ExpectedStatusCode>200</ExpectedStatusCode>
</HttpOptions>
</Monitor>
</Monitors>
<Policy>
<LoadBalancingMethod>Performance</LoadBalancingMethod>
<Endpoints/>
<MonitorStatus>Inactive</MonitorStatus>
</Policy>
</Definition>
</Definitions>
```

**UPDATE3**
This sporadic behavior is ONLY happening with the specific cloud services and TM profile/definitiona. When I create new set of cloud services and TM profile, then everything seems to be working fine. I tested this multiple times. So the only problem is with following parameters.

- endpoint1 domain name - JASH13.CLOUDAPP.NET
- endpoint2 domain name -JASH23.CLOUDAPP.NET
- TM Domain - ramitm.trafficmanager.net
- TM profilename - ramitm

Comment: Share some code please.

Comment: @GauravMantri, Added code above.

Comment: @ramiramilu can you share any information about the WATM profile you created?  The WATM URL or one of your cloudapp.net URLs would be helpful.  I can lookup this information in our internal logs and see what happened.

Comment: @kwill Sure. These are the details - WATM - ramitm.trafficmanager.net endpoint1 - jash13.cloudapp.net endpoint2 - jash23.cloudapp.net

Comment: @kwill - I looked the profile definition once the TM went into inactive. I was not able to find endpoints in the definition.

Comment: @kwill One more observation, if I create TM with a different Profile Name and Domain Name along with different cloud services. Then everything seems to be working fine. This sporadic behavior is only happening with the specific cloud services I mentioned in my above comment.

Comment: @ramiramilu are you sure you are using jash13.cloudapp.net and  jash23.cloudapp.net?  Those services do not exist.

Comment: @kwill, I deleted them just yesterday because of the reason that they are costing me without being helpful. But I can reproduce the same Traffic Manager problem with them, if you want. You can check Azure TM logs of Nov 22 and 23, at that time they do exist. And in fact at that time they are completely functional.

Comment: @ramiramilu It would be helpful if you could provide some timestamps for when you saw this issue.  I see a Create Definition at 08:26 UTC on Nov 22 with both jash13 and jash23 endpoints, but then the profile was deleted 30 seconds later.  Then I see another Create Definition 30 minutes later with both endpoints, then a Create Definition an hour later with only jash13, followed immediately by a Create Definition with no endpoints, and then a delete profile 2 minutes later.  Then an hour and a half later another Create Definition with both endpoints, and a delete profile the following day.

Comment: In short, it looks like you are doing a lot of editing of the endpoints, and some of your edits are specifically removing the endpoints.

Comment: @kwill I was doing testing of some scripts. Let me rerun the scripts and try to replicate the same scenario. Then I will share you all the details. Give me some time. Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems like some DNS Problems for very fast REST API Operations. I was not able to get the crux of the problem, but this is how I solved it.

Previously I was getting this problem for this patter - **Create -> Delete -> Re-Create**

Now I made it this way - **Create -> Delete -> Delay -> Re-Create**

I think by introducing delay component, I am giving enough time for Azure to settle down all the DNS and infrastructure and there by update them. So after introducing delay, I was not experiencing the problem. Delay can be 5 - 10 mins.