# Cannot set up azure website from gallery

Tags: azure, gallery

Trying to create new website from Gallery using Orchard or Umbraco fails. It shows as set up then immediately fails, removes itself from the list with the error message  - 'Cannot contact server to determine the state of web site'

If I retry, the chosen url is taken so it has registered it somewhere

Answer (score 0):

These kind of things happen with most of the cloud platforms. In fact I kind of [experienced this with Azure Traffic Manager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20145085/creating-azure-traffic-manager-through-rest-api-unexpected-behaviour). Give it some time and RETRY again and it will be fine. I am confirming that I was able to create Orchard Website right now in Azure.

> if I retry, the chosen url is taken so it has registered it somewher

It might take some time for Azure to flush all DNS entries, usually 5 - 10 mins (in my experience). Once done, you should be able to use your chosen urls, unless they are already taken by some other persons.